# Notepad++ weird bug? when replace a huge string

Tags: regex, string, notepad++, newline

I'm getting a `CR` `LF` characters after replacing a huge string with Notepad++.
Moreover, The string add a line break in places which I didn't ask.

Weird...

Here is the print screen:

[image]

Those `CR` `LF` character haven't been there before I was using string replace (or they where hidden? and if so why the string replace revealed them?)

Is there is a quick (regex?) solution to remove them ?
Is there any quick (regex?) solution to remove any characters that is NOT [a-z] [A-Z] [0-9] ["|'] OR NON UTF-8 characters ?

Comment: Notepad or Notepad++ ?

Comment: inside a character class `|` is no more an OR operator but a simple literal character, you can remove it. *(see a tutorial about character classes to well understand what they are)*

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte: Oh, I was assuming the pipe was one of the punctuation characters he wanted to keep, but I think you're right that he didn't intend that.

Comment: @BrianStephens: me too at the begining, but no more since his last comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just replace `\r\n` with nothing, and that will remove the line breaks.

To remove any character that is not `[a-z][A-Z][0-9]["|']`, replace `[^A-Za-z0-9"|']` with nothing. But be careful that you've thought of everything you do want to keep: spaces, tabs, other punctuation, etc.

Comment: @davidmarko: Be sure the search mode is set to Regular expression, but otherwise it should work.

Comment: Forgot to keep the spaces :) [^A-Za-z0-9"|'| ]

Comment: I found a bug on Notepad++... but... Problem Solved! Thanks Man!